# How to give feedback to an immutable page at wiki.ubuntu.com

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I want to give feedback to this page since I am missing something.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports

I have a login for this site, but since the page is immutable, I can't change it.

How can I give feedback if I am missing something an a wiki.ubuntu.com page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Ever since the bad people with bad intentions wreaking havoc on the wiki pages daily incidents of June 2016, the original answer here has been obsolete.

This is a the main [ubuntu wiki reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide), where in addition to a launchpad account, also membership in the [Ubuntu Wiki Editors team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wiki-editors) is also required.

DO NOT submit a bug report to the [Ubuntu-Docs project](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs) about immutable wiki pages. It will get set to "INVALID" status.

Original Answer:

That is odd, the page is not immutable for me. For immutable pages you can file a bug report on Lauchpad under the [ubuntu-docs project](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs/). However, note that if the page is not actually immutable the bug report will be set to invalid.

Note also that there is often confusion about the login requirements and people often think a page is immutable when it is not. [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide) should help.

Comment: Strange, I checked it again. It is immutable for me. Maybe you need some kind of score to be able to edit it.

Comment: I am not aware that I have any special privileges for the wiki stuff (I do for the launchpad docs stuff). I am aware that often we get people thinking a page is immutable when it actually isn't. Anyway, if you file a bug report, I'll make sure it doesn't get set to invalid (or if it does while I am not paying attention, I'll revert it). In the end, your feedback should not be lost.

Comment: Today the page is not immutable any more. I guess the wiki backend does some kind of caching. Yesterday I was not logged and read the page. Then I logged in and the page was still immutable. Looks like a caching issue to me.

Comment: Here the issue about pages being immutable although user is logged in: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1462200

Comment: I meant you could file a bug report against the immutable page, and what you wanted done to it. The doc team cann't do anything about whatever was going on with access. Anyway, since you now have edit access to the page, please go ahead and do your edit.

Comment: I created a ticket. It is a know issue that pages are still immutable after login. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1462200/

Answer (score 3):

I had to do two things in order to be able to edit the wiki:

1. My Launchpad/Ubuntu account to be added to ["Ubuntu Wiki Editors" team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wiki-editors)
2. Relog to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ with option "Team membership: ubuntu-wiki-editors" checked.

Comment: I can confirm this was also the procedure that worked for me, as of 2021.

Answer (score 2):

A page will pretend to be *Immutable* until

1. [your Launchpad/Ubuntu account has been added to the ''ubuntu-etherpad'' group](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide) (which requires approval by a team admin), and
2. you have logged in with that account and the option *Team membership: ubuntu-etherpad* enabled.

IRC channel #ubuntu-doc on freenode helped me out.