# Do I edit the wifi help page on the ubuntu wiki?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I have an Ubuntu one and a launchpad account (I am logged in) but, when I go to [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide) I don't see any way to edit the page.

The thing I wanted to edit was replacing `nm-tool` with `nmcli`

Comment: Do you have an account with a group `ubuntu-wiki-editor` ?

Comment: i do not know what that is

Comment: Read the link at the bottom of the page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide

Comment: it just brings me back to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WikiGuide

Comment: You need to be a member of this group to edit - https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wiki-editors

Comment: Wiki changed as per your request. ([history can be see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide?action=info))   Thank you for noticing the issue, trying to address it & seeking help.

Comment: FYI:  You can seek help for like issues on IRC in #ubuntu-doc & like rooms (*and you can access IRC using a browser though webchat links aren't shown for team rooms on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList but I just tested it and it works in #ubuntu-doc*); of course you'll need to be patient for replies on small *team* rooms such as that one, but if you have issues with how I edited the page etc, IRC is where I can be found; or you find other pages needing correction & don't have privileges

Comment: Dupe of https://askubuntu.com/a/1079246/158442, but anyway the change has been made

Comment: Of interest: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20003/57576

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give feedback to an immutable page at wiki.ubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632048/how-to-give-feedback-to-an-immutable-page-at-wiki-ubuntu-com)

Comment: @guiverc You've given what amounts to a very good answer over a few comments, of several ways to push changes to the Wiki. Could you convert them to an answer to make sure they have some lasting value for others? (Yes, there may be past questions on this with their own answers but the stuff covered here seems to go well beyond)

Answer (score 1):

You [*generally*] need to be a member of this group to edit wiki pages - [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wiki-editors](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-wiki-editors).  FYI:  I used the word *generally* as being a member of certain groups/teams automatically gives you rights/privileges of other teams.

You can seek help for like issues on [IRC](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC) in #ubuntu-doc & like rooms (*and you can access IRC using a browser though webchat links aren't shown for team rooms on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList but I just tested it and it works in #ubuntu-doc*); of course you'll need to be patient for replies on small team rooms such as that one.

I've made a number of changes on the actual wiki because I've seen questions on this site (*plus others too, inc. ML & other forms of media*) as I have access (*refer back to the comments on this thread currently for an example*), and I'll not be alone.

FYI:  I suspect IRC is still such as useful tool as a number of *oldies* can be found there, but you'll also find a lot of Ubuntu members, Canonical employees leave IRC clients/bouncers running so we can scan when we have the time.

Comment: Answer made as per suggestion by @Oli ^ based primarily on my comments (*with redactions for details I was intended to be used only by OP, plus expansion too mainly on IRC*)

Comment: The most common group that grants edit rights to the wiki besides ubuntu-wiki-editors is ubuntu-members.